# Double.parseDouble() no muestra los decimales 0

Tags: java, android, double

Tenga una aplicación donde se deben de mostras los precios de unos productos, si el precio es por ejemplo 7,95 va perfecto, pero cuando es 7,90 al hacer el  `Double.parseDouble` me lo redondea automaticamente a 7,9, quiero que el valor obtenido siempre tenga 2 decimales. Dejo código de mi aplicación.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String newPrice = df.format(countPrice - price);
newPrice = newPrice.replace(",", ".");
countPrice = Double.parseDouble(newPrice);
//Este ultimo metodo es el del problema, ya lo he comprobado con logs, newPrice antes de parsearlo tiene el valor correcto
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: 7,90 es igual a 7,9 cuando lo guardas en un Double. Lo de que tenga o no más de un decimal es cuando lo representas como una cadena de caracteres, no cuando lo guardas en el double. Al convertir a Double, obviamente te quita el cero y guarda 7,9. Cuando lo vas a mostrar como cadena en pantalla, en fichero, en un log o lo que sea es cuando te tienes que preocupar de que quede con el formato que tú quieres.

Comment: Como te dice @SuperG280 solo tienes que preocuparte al representar tu float... Mira por ejemplo como se puede pasar un formato en el "toString", y puedes indicar cuantos decimales se muestran, incluso si son ceros.

Comment: muchas gracias chicos tenéis razon y ya esta solucionado este pequeño problema